# it looks like I have something installed 22.0l01 but it breaks something else. This is preventing me from updating my OS. Output below

Tags: apt, dpkg, dependencies

```
althecalboom@Alexander-Linx:~$ sudo apt update
[sudo] password for althecalboom: 
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease [109 kB]
Hit:3 https://repo.steampowered.com/steam stable InRelease           
Get:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease [99.8 kB]
Hit:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease     
Get:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages [255 kB]
Hit:7 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ernstp/mesarc/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Get:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main i386 Packages [119 kB]
Get:9 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main Translation-en [65.3 kB]
Get:10 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe i386 Packages [40.2 kB]
Get:11 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 Packages [110 kB]
Get:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe Translation-en [37.2 kB]
Hit:13 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/lutris-team/lutris/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Fetched 836 kB in 1s (702 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
2 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
althecalboom@Alexander-Linx:~$ sudo apt autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgl1-mesa-dri : Depends: libglapi-mesa (= 22.0.1-1ubuntu2) but 22.1.1+git2206012350.53c72db5d3c~j~mesarc0 is installed
                   Breaks: libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 (!= 22.0.1-1ubuntu2) but 22.1.1+git2206012350.53c72db5d3c~j~mesarc0 is installed
 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 : Breaks: libgl1-mesa-dri (!= 22.1.1+git2206012350.53c72db5d3c~j~mesarc0) but 22.0.1-1ubuntu2 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
althecalboom@Alexander-Linx:~$ apt --fix-broken install
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?
althecalboom@Alexander-Linx:~$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgl1-mesa-dri : Depends: libglapi-mesa (= 22.0.1-1ubuntu2) but 22.1.1+git2206012350.53c72db5d3c~j~mesarc0 is installed
                   Breaks: libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 (!= 22.0.1-1ubuntu2) but 22.1.1+git2206012350.53c72db5d3c~j~mesarc0 is installed
 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 : Breaks: libgl1-mesa-dri (!= 22.1.1+git2206012350.53c72db5d3c~j~mesarc0) but 22.0.1-1ubuntu2 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: Still new to Linux, so I have no idea what I am doing in the long term.

Comment: Looks like you installed mesa drivers from some non-Ubuntu source. It's listed among your sources. Do you recall doing so?

Comment: Sort of, I tried installing CoreCtrl, maybe that. I also have downloaded FFXIV third party launcher. I have downloaded the usual steam, discord, flakpak, and wine.

Comment: You need sudo for `sudo apt --fix-broken install` - but then you will probably need to `sudo apt purge apt libgl1-mesa-dri=22.1.1+git2206012350.53c72db5d3c~j~mesarc0` - for the version of libgl1-mesa-dri (to get it out of the way of the standard version), but I haven't tried similar things... so cannot direct you more exactly.

Comment: what happens if I purge it? oh and this came up after that putting in sudo apt --fix-broken install

Comment: dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libgl1-mesa-dri
_22.1.1+git2206012350.53c72db5d3c~j~mesarc0_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i915_dri.so', whic
h is also in package libgl1-amber-dri:amd64 21.3.7-0ubuntu1  
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libgl1-mesa-dri_22.1.1+git2206012350.53c72db5
d3c~j~mesarc0_amd64.deb

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: That error message means that you tried installing the same set of mesa drivers from TWO different sources. Stop doing that. Uninstall both.

Comment: Oh I see, basically since it’s already formatted in someway, so I can’t do anything to it, unless I remove the current format. Which means it would be safe for me to delete that format then? I am assuming so.

Comment: Sort of did, but I somehow deleted the GUI in the process, no idea how, but I may have removed a critical PPA from the list. So I just decided to nuke it and reinstall everything, since everything is still newish.